# Bluetooth retransmission

Tags: audio, bluetooth, ubuntu

I'm doing a project of automation, and I would like to implement a bluetooth "retransmitter" for sound. I'm currently using Raspberry PI 4 (4gb ram) with ubuntu desktop client 20.10

This is what I need:

Any transmitter of bluetooth (like cell phone) > Raspberry PI sound capture > Bluetooth Speakers

instead of

Any transmitter of bluetooth (like cell phone)  > Bluetooth Speakers

This is because I need to capture the sound to process in Raspberry PI. Of course I will need a bluetooth dongle of some kind, maybe a chip that I can connect to the Rasp.

Any ideas?